# How to parse html with wget to download an artifact using pattern matching against Jenkins

Tags: bash, curl, jenkins, wget

I am trying to download an artifact from Jenkins where I need the latest build. If I `curl` `jenkins.mycompany.com/view/iOS/job/build_ios/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build` it brings me to the page that contains the artifact I need to download, which in my case is `myCompany-1234.ipa`

so by changing `curl` to `wget` with `--auth-no-challenge https://userIsMe:123myapikey321@jenkins.mycompany.com/view/iOS/job/build_ios/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/` it downloads the `index.html` file.

if I put `--reject index.html` it stops the index.html downloading.

if I add the name of the artifact with a wildcard like so `MyCompany-*.ipa`it downloads a 14k file named `MyCompany-*.ipa`, not the `MyCompany-1234.ipa` I was hoping for. Keep in mind the page i am requesting only has 1 `MyCompany-1234.ipa` so there will never be multiple matches found

if I use a flag to pattern match `-A "*.ipa"` like so: `wget --auth-no-challenge -A "*.ipa" https://userIsMe:123myapikey321@jenkins.mycompany.com/view/iOS/job/build_ios/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/` It still doesn't download the artifact.

It works if I perfectly input the exact url like so: `wget --auth-no-challenge https://userIsMe:123myapikey321@jenkins.mycompany.com/view/iOS/job/build_ios/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/MyCompany-1234.ipa`

The problem here is the .ipa is not always going to be 1234, tomorrow will be 1235, and so on. How can I either parse the html or use the wildcard correctly in wget to ensure I am always getting the latest?

Answer (score 0):

NM, working with another engineer here at my work came up with a super elegant solution parsing json.

1. Install Chrome and get the plugin `JSONView`
2. Call the Jenkins API in your Chrome browser using `https://$domain/$job/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json`
   This will print out the key pair values in json. Denote your Key, for me it was `number`
3. brew install `jq`
4. In a bash script create a variable that will store the dynamic value as follows

This will store the build number to latest:

`latest=$(curl --silent --show-error https://userIsMe:123myapikey321@jenkins.mycompany.com/job/build_ios/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json | jq '.number')`

Print it to screen if you would like:

`echo $latest`

Now with some string interpolation pass the variable for latest to your wget call:

`wget --auth-no-challenge https://userIsMe:123myapikey321@jenkins.mycompany.com/view/iOS/job/build_ios/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/myCompany-$latest.ipa`

Hope this helps someone out as there is limited info out there that is clear and concise, especially given that wget has been around for an eternity.

Comment: As documented on the API page, you can use `/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber` to retrieve the build number in plain text.

Comment: @ChristopherOrr ahhh..OK and I put that in my string and mentioned I was able to do that. What I was asking was how to download the artifact and parse using pattern matching with wget. I ended up using the Jenkins API to retrieve Json as I listed above in my last post. If you only use `/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber` it return the index.html which I also mentioning the initial post. if you curl it it returns the entire html page. you have to use the Jenkins API correctly like I showed above `https://$domain/$job/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json`. Thanks?

Comment: Right, but there's no magical pattern matching features in wget or Jenkins. I wasn't supplying an alternative answer — just trying to improve this existing answer. i.e. there's no need to use the JSON API or `jq`.

Comment: There is a a recursive and pattern flag in wget, I just couldn't get it to work like I was hoping. `-r` and `-A "*.ipa"` And what is a JSON API? You mean Jenkins API and ask for the response in JSON?

Comment: You are using the JSON API right now in your answer. You're retrieving information about the build from the `<build>/api/json` URL, and then extracting the build number. I was just saying you don't need that, as there's the `<build>/buildNumber` URL.

Comment: In any case, your existing answer here is the most efficient. Recursive wget would work, but you have to be very careful when using it, especially as there are various download and metadata URLs for every artifact. What would likely work is: `wget -r -np -nd -erobots=off -A '*.ipa' --reject-regex '/\*.+\*/|auto_refresh'' https://<build>/artifact/build/`

Comment: (Or, at the end of your build, rename the `.ipa` file so that it has a constant name; or create a symlink to the `.ipa` with a constant name, and archive that)